In a MudBlazor DataGrid, how can I use inline editing and also use TemplateColumn?
I'm using a MudBlazor DataGrid with cells that use TemplateColumn for custom color. I would like to use EditMode="DataGridEditMode.Cell" for inline editing, but when I do I lose the TemplateColumn.
Is there a way to turn on inline editing only for the selected row? Using DataGridEditTrigger.OnRowClick" does not work.
https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wYcIPPcvKUrbAtTK

Do you mean you don't want the TemplateColumn to be editable?

I do want it editable. I'm looking for it to be a textbox when the row is in edit mode and colored text when it is not.

You already have that in your snippet though. Can you elaborate on what you're looking for.

I think you could use PropertyColumn instead of TemplateColumn to make cell inline editing work.
<MudDataGrid Items="@Tests" T="Test" ReadOnly="false" EditMode="DataGridEditMode.Cell" >
    <Columns>
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Id" Title="Id" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x=>x.Compliant" Title="Compliant"/>
        <PropertyColumn Property="x=>x" Title="Compliant Color">
            <EditTemplate>
                <MudTextField Style="@(context.Item.Compliant.StartsWith("N")?"color: red":"")" @bind-Value="context.Item.Compliant"></MudTextField>
            </EditTemplate>
        </PropertyColumn>
    </Columns>
</MudDataGrid>

@code {
    private List<Test> Tests = new()
    {
        new Test { Id = 1, Compliant = "Yes"},
        new Test { Id = 2, Compliant = "No" }
    };

    public class Test
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Compliant { get; set; }
    }
}

When you modify the "PropertyColumn" by "EditTemplate", the default template is removed. So it doesn't even matter what the "Property" is, just use Property="x=>x".
